# Change Colorbox interface to make a print button

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Colorbox has a number of controllable regions to assist with navigation, titles and closing. I'm wanting to add one for printing the content but don't know the best way to go about adding it without hacking the plug-in - which I really don't want to do.

It looks like the structure is generated in the publicMethod.init() function so I guess I would want to append a

```
$print = $tag(div, "Print"),
```

to the $content variable inside that function.

Any ideas on the best approach for adding this when colorbox is specified?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up taking the following approach and thought it might help
others who want to set-up a similar print function within Colorbox.
I needed to load some dynamic information into colorbox to start with,
then a button is clicked and new information is loaded that can be
printed. The print button is only to appear on the second colorbox.

### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".intro_modal").colorbox({
            inline:true,
            innerWidth:600,
            height:300,
            onLoad: function() {
                    // Remove print if it is re-opened after ajax
                    $("#cboxPrint").remove();
            },
    });

    $(".checklist_ajax").colorbox({
            iframe:true,
            innerWidth:800,
            height:"95%",
            onComplete: function() {
                    $("#cboxContent iframe").ready(function(){
                            // Add print box once content loaded
                            $("#cboxContent").append('<div id="cboxPrint" style="float: left;">print</div>');
                            $("#cboxPrint").click( function() {
                                    printprepare();
                            });
                    });
            },
    });

});

function printprepare(){
    try{
            var print_frame = document.getElementById('ifrmPrint');
            var print_head = $("#cboxContent iframe").contents().find("head").html();
            var print_body = $("#cboxContent iframe").contents().find("body").html()
            var print_doc = (print_frame.contentWindow || print_frame.contentDocument);
            if (print_doc.document) print_doc = print_doc.document;
            // Write printable content
            print_doc.write("<html><head>");
            print_doc.write(print_head);
            print_doc.write('</head><body onload="this.focus(); this.print();">');
            print_doc.write(print_body);
            print_doc.write("</body></html>");
            print_doc.close();
    }
    catch(e){
            self.print();
    }
}
```

---

I had been struggling with '$("#cboxContent iframe").load(function()'... but ready() '$("#cboxContent iframe").ready(function()' worked once the content was loaded.
this.focus() and this.print() needed to be added to the body to affect
the print.

### The HTML:

```
...
<p><a class='intro_modal' href="#inline_content" title="Checklist">Button</a></p>
...
<div style="display:none">
    <div style="padding:10px; background:#fff;" id="inline_content">
            <p>Inline content here...</p>
            <p><a href="link/to/printable/content" class="checklist_ajax cboxElement" title="Checklist">Click here to load content</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<iframe id="ifrmPrint" src="#" style="width:0pt; height:0pt; border: none;"></iframe>
```

CSS then made to suit.

Comment: hi sorry to drag this thread up from 2011, but i am looking to do something similer, but rather than have the the print button appear on the second colorbox, i want it to appear on the initial colorbox and to print what is in that colorbox window.

has this become possible in the years that have passed?